# Error: Unknown column <value> in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

got a problem with `mysql`.

im trying to update an value, from an existing table entry.

The table is called `Parts`

the columns are `Part` and `Quantity`

one of the entries has `Part=keks`  and `Quantity=10`

now im trying to:

```
UPDATE Parts SET Quantity=20 WHERE Part = keks
```

but this error appear:

```
Error: Unknown column 'keks' in 'where clause'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes:

```
UPDATE Parts SET Quantity=20 WHERE Part = 'keks'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the search term in quotes:

```
 UPDATE Parts SET Quantity=20 WHERE Part = keks
```

becomes

```
 UPDATE Parts SET Quantity=20 WHERE Part = 'keks'
```

Note, the Quantity could also be in quotes, but because it is a number, it doesn't need to be.

Answer (score 1):

you should insert your `' '` in your where clause single quote

```
UPDATE Parts SET Quantity=20 WHERE Part = 'keks'
```

Answer (score 1):

What the MySQL interpreter understands is that you want to update the table `Parts` and set the column `Quantity` as 20 to every row where the column `Part` has the same value as a (**non-existing**) column `keks`.

As other people already said, if you want to tell the interpreter to compare the column to a **value**, you should wrap the value with *quotes*, like this: **`'keks'`**

So, in the end your query will be:

```
UPDATE Parts SET Quantity=20 WHERE Part = 'keks'
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
WHERE Part = 'keks'
```